# Update dynamic Json without Pojo classes by dyamic keys in java

Tags: json

{"requestBody":"{\r\n  \"ProcedureCode\" : \"RT\",\r\n  \"ProcedureVersion\" : 1,\r\n  \"FacilityGlobalID\" : \"\",\r\n  \"FacilityID\" : \"\",\r\n  \"FacilityType\" : \"\",\r\n  \"SurveyAreaID\" : \"RTSURVEY1\",\r\n  \"SurveyAreaType\" : \"FDR27KV\",\r\n  \"ProcedureSteps\" : [ {\r\n    \"ProcedureStepUniquelD\" : \"10349\",\r\n    \"ProcedureStepID\" : \"\",\r\n    \"DeleteStep\" : \"\",\r\n    \"StepCode\" : \"RTSTEPS\",\r\n    \"StepDescription\" : \"TEST\",\r\n    \"StepActualDateTime\" : \"2018-06-06T09:15:31.176Z\",\r\n    \"StepCompletionDateTime\" : \"2018-06-06T09:15:31.176Z\",\r\n    \"StepCompletedByPersonNumber\" : 16,\r\n    \"StepCompletedByEmail\" : \"\",\r\n    \"StepCompletedByCoEmployeeID\" : \"\",\r\n    \"CrewID\" : \"3982\",\r\n    \"Comment\" : \"TEST COMMENT\",\r\n    \"Instruction\" : \"\",\r\n    \"StepAction\" : \"\",\r\n    \"RepetitionSequence\" : null,\r\n    \"ReportName\" : \"TEST\",\r\n    \"SpatialID\" : null,\r\n    \"SpatialX\" : 0,\r\n    \"SpatialY\" : 0,\r\n    \"ProcedureStepGroupUniqueID\" : \"\",\r\n    \"InsertionDate\" : \"2018-06-06\",\r\n    \"FacilityGlobalID\" : \"\",\r\n    \"FacilityID\" : \"RTFAC1\",\r\n    \"FacilityType\" : \"POLE\",\r\n    \"ComponentGlobalID\" : \"\",\r\n    \"ComponentID\" : \"\",\r\n    \"ComponentType\" : \"\",\r\n    \"AssetSequenceNumber\" : 0,\r\n    \"ProcedureStepResults\" : [ {\r\n      \"Result\" : \"115\",\r\n      \"ResultDescription\" : \"\"\r\n    } ],\r\n    \"ProcedureStepFollowupWorkRequests\" : [ {\r\n      \"FollowupWorkRequestGlobalID\" : \"1234\",\r\n      \"FollowUpWorkRequestNumberType\" : \"WMIS\",\r\n      \"ResultCode\" : \"\"\r\n    } ]\r\n  } ],\r\n  \"Conditions\" : [ {\r\n    \"ConditionGlobalID\" : \"\",\r\n    \"ConditionID\" : \"1966\",\r\n    \"NewCondition\" : \"N\",\r\n    \"ConditionName\" : \"\",\r\n    \"ConditionStatus\" : \"\",\r\n    \"Delete\" : \"\",\r\n    \"EnteredDateTime\" : \"2018-06-05T09:15:31.177Z\",\r\n    \"DateTimeOpened\" : \"2018-06-05T09:15:31.177Z\",\r\n    \"DateTimeClosed\" : null,\r\n    \"OpenedByPersonNumber\" : null,\r\n    \"OpenedByEmail\" : \"sunitha\",\r\n    \"EnteredByPersonNumber\" : null,\r\n    \"EnteredByPersonEmail\" : \"sunitha\",\r\n    \"ClosedByPersonNumber\" : null,\r\n    \"ClosedByPersonEmail\" : \"sunitha.subash.\",\r\n    \"SurveyAreaID\" : \"\",\r\n    \"SurveyAreaType\" : \"\",\r\n    \"FacilityGlobalID\" : \"\",\r\n    \"FacilityID\" : \"\",\r\n    \"FacilityType\" : \"\",\r\n    \"ComponentGlobalID\" : \"\",\r\n    ,\r\n    \"Address13\" : \"\",\r\n    \"Address14\" : \"\",\r\n    \"Address15\" : \"\",\r\n    \"SpatialD\" : \"\",\r\n    \"SpatialX\" : \"0\",\r\n    \"SpatialY\" : \"0\",\r\n    \"ConditionDetail\" : [ {\r\n      \"ConditionDetailGlobalID\" : \"\",\r\n      \"Action\" : \"\",\r\n      \"ActionDescription\" : \"\",\r\n      \"Comments\" : \"\",\r\n      \"CreditProcedure\" : \"\",\r\n      \"CrewCode\" : \"\",\r\n      \"Outcome\" : \"\",\r\n      \"OutcomeDescription\" : \"\",\r\n      \"ConditionType\" : \"CI003\",\r\n      \"UpdateDateTime\" : \"2018-06-06T09:15:31.178Z\",\r\n      \"UpdatedByPersonNumber\" : null,\r\n      \"UpdatedByEmail\" : \"sunitha.subash.chandra.bose@.com\",\r\n      \"UpdatedByCoEmployeeID\" : \"\",\r\n      \"FollowUpWorkRequestType\" : \"\",\r\n      \"FollowupWorkRequestGlobalID\" : \"\",\r\n      \"ConditionDetailAttributes\" : [ {\r\n        \"AttributeCode\" : \"CFR\",\r\n        \"AttributeValue\" : \"NO\",\r\n        \"Copy\" : \"\",\r\n        \"UpdateableAfterCopy\" : \"N\"\r\n      } ]\r\n    } ],\r\n    \"ConditionAttachments\" : [ {\r\n      \"FileName\" : \"TEST.TXT\",\r\n      \"PathName\" : \"\",\r\n      \"AttachmentDescription\" : \"\",\r\n      \"Comments\" : \"\",\r\n      \"AttachmentDateTime\" : null,\r\n      \"AttachedByPersonNumber\" : 16,\r\n      \"AttachedByPersonEmail\" : \"\",\r\n      \"AttachedByPersonCoEmployeeID\" : \"\",\r\n      \"AttachedByPersonGenID\" : \"\"\r\n    } ]\r\n  } ],\r\n  \"SurveyedFacilities\" : [ {\r\n    \"FacilityGlobalId\" : \"\",\r\n    \"FacilityType\" : \"POLE\",\r\n    \"FacilityID\" : \"RTFAC1\",\r\n    \"DateSurveyed\" : \"2018-06-06T09:15:31.178Z\",\r\n    \"SurveyedByPersonNumber\" : 16,\r\n    \"SurveyedByEmail\" : \"\",\r\n    \"SurveyedByCoEmployeeID\" : \"\",\r\n    \"ModifiedByPersonNumber\" : 16,\r\n    \"UpdateTimestamp\" : null,\r\n    \"SurveyedFacilityConditions\" : [ {\r\n      \"ConditionGlobalID\" : \"\",\r\n      \"ConditionID\" : \"1966\"\r\n    } ]\r\n  } ]\r\n}","requestURL":"http://131:9082/Server/work/id/~2414/results","requestHeader":"{                 \"RequestDateTime\":\"2018-03-21T10:29:52Z\",                 \"VendorName\":\"Vendor101\",                 \"AppName\":\"WM\",                 \"UserID\":\"IT1\",                 \"ServiceDetails\":\"iOS|11.2.6|Cell\",                 \"ReportingCrewID\":\"Crew101\",                 \"ReportingPersonNumber\":12345,                 \"ReportingPersonEmail\":\"person1@domain.com\"}"}

This is my sample Json. It has complex JsonObjects and JSONarray inside JsonArray.

User will update n number of key values from UI based on this json.

For ex:
 ProcedureCode key inside requestBody can be updated from UI
 ProcedureStepUniquelD inside ProcedureSteps (that is inside requestBody) can be updated from UI.

I need to update the above json and form same structure as above and save in to data base using with uodated keys.

Note that the sample json is a dynamic one. can not be same as given above.

Please let me know how can i do update the json in the same format without pojo classes.

Comment: You can try with org.json or any Json libraries and parse the Json string to JSON object.Instead of a POJO class you can use this Json object for further operation.